# Javascript - XMLHttpRequest failing in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, xmlhttprequest, xml-parsing

*** SOLVED *** Answer is in separate post below

This code runs fine in FireFox but it will not run in Internet Explorer 8. It gives me the error of "access denied. Is there something I am missing?

```
function loadXMLDoc(dname){
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
        var xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else{
        var xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xhttp.open("GET", dname,false);
    xhttp.send();
    return xhttp.responseXML;
}
var xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("notSchema.xml");
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('ROOT_NODE_ID');
```

It specifically doesn't like the .open() and the .send()

Edited...

```
var x;

function loadXMLDoc(dname){
var request = $.ajax({
    url: dname,
    type: "GET",
    async: false,
    data: {},
    success: function(http){
        xmlDoc = http;
        alert(http);
        x=http.getElementsByTagName("ROOT_NODE_ID");
    },
    error: function(html){
        alert('failure: ' + html);
    }       
});

}

loadXMLDoc("notSchema.xml");

for (var i=0;i<x.length;i++)
{

if(x[i].childNodes[0] == undefined) {
    treeArray[count]="null";
    count++;
}else{
    //return ROOT_NODE_ID

    treeArray[count]=x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    count++;
}
}
```

Edited the Code once again. What I'm trying to do is load the XML, parse for the tag "ROOT_NODE_ID" and then get that value and store it into an array

When I run that code in firefox, it returns 51, which is the number of ROOT_NODE_ID tags and fills the tree that I am making.
When I run the same exact code in IE8, it does not even alert.

I'm Stumped.

Comment: Try using `Msxml2.XMLHTTP` instead of `Microsoft.XMLHTTP`. Also, where are you testing this? Is it a local file?

Comment: This is a local file and IE8 seems to be using XMLHttpRequest and not going to the 'else' statement.

Comment: Why not just use jQuery to abstract all of this for you?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean JP. All I know is that this runs perfectly in Firefox and it doesn't run in IE and I'm baffled. I did try Msxml2.XMLHTTP but the tree that I'm creating still is non existent

Comment: Not trying to be rude, but googling this issue seems to reveal many similar scenarios - http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=ie+xml+request+access+denied

Comment: IE has had `XMLHttpRequest` since version 7.  That other stuff is to cater to IE6, and should be thrown out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Like I said before, if you run the code above in Firefox, it returns the 'object' and if you run it in IE8, it returns the contents of the object. I solved this problem by loading the content of the object again in IE8, thus turning the content of the object back into an object that will be ready to be parsed. If that makes any sense.

Just to clarify to people that are just visiting this thread. When I called 'alert(http);' in firefox, it would return '[object XMLDocument]', but in IE8 it would return the actual contents of '[object XMLDocument]'.

```
var treeArray=new Array();
var count = 0;
var x;

function loadXMLDoc(dname){
var request = $.ajax({
    url: dname,
    type: "GET",
    async: false,
    data: {},
    success: function(http){
        var xmlDocument = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
        //Loading the contents of the object 'http' a second time, which turns it into an object again. 
        xmlDocument.loadXML(http);
        x = xmlDocument.getElementsByTagName("ROOT_NODE_ID");
        alert(x.length);
    },
    error: function(html){
        alert('failure: ' + html);
    }       
});

}

loadXMLDoc("notSchema.xml");

for (var i=0;i<x.length;i++)
{

if(x[i].childNodes[0] == undefined) {
    treeArray[count]="null";
    count++;
}else{
    //return ROOT_NODE_ID

    treeArray[count]=x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    count++;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Zack,

You can use jquery to do the ajax call - jquery will do everything properly behind the curtains.

In your case here:

```
function loadXMLDoc(dname){
var request = $.ajax({
    url: dname,
    type: "GET",
    async: false,
    data: {},
    success: function(html){

          var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('ROOT_NODE_ID');    

    },
    error: function(html){
        alert('failure: ' + html);
    }   
});
```

}

Comment: It pulls the XML correctly but how would I then execute              

var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('ROOT_NODE_ID')

i.e. Parse the reponse

Comment: Alright so all of my parsing code would go in the success function.  Correction? var x=html.getElementsByTagName('ROOT_NODE_ID');

Comment: I edited my original post with updated code. Works in Firefox, not in IE8

Comment: do an alert(html) in the success function so you can see if there is any response at all.

Comment: There is a response. In Firefox, the alert displays "[object XMLDocument]" In IE8 the alert displays the actual XML code.

Comment: Edited the Code once again showing what exactly I'm trying to do.

Comment: So in firefox you get the object in IE8 you get the actual contents of the file. BUt you are getting a result in IE8 - so the XMLHTTP request is WORKING. How you handle it from here is a different topic.